# Suppress spring-boot logs when compiling with maven

Tags: spring-boot, maven-3, spring-logback

Im looking for a solution to set log level during compile time. All the guides I can find only sets log level on runtime. 
[Baeldung guide](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-changing-log-level-at-runtime)[Spring Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-logging)

We have a spring-boot application and using maven. When running

```
mvn clean install
```

or any other lifecycle command we get a massive amount of logs from the following packages:

```
o.apache.tomcat.util.digester 
o.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils
```

example of the output.
[image]

is there any why to suppress logs from this packages when compiling.

we have tried to configure the logback.

```
<logger name="o.apache.tomcat.util" level="OFF"/>
```

also tried to configure application.properties file with the same result.

```
logging.level.o.apache.tomcat.util=debug
```

Both this configurations work at runtime but not compile time.

Comment: What do you mean by "compile time"?  Do you mean setting the default log level?  This can be done simply by adding the following line to `application.properties`: `logging.level.org.springframework=DEBUG`

Comment: I've edited the question to better explain my issue.

Comment: Have you tried `org.apache.tomcat.util` as the logger name?

Comment: Nice thanks @AndyWilkinson

Answer (score 0):

successfully suppressed logs by adding to applications.properties.

```
logging.level.org.apache.tomcat.util=off
```